# How can I choose higher difficulty levels after beating Diablo 3 in normal?

Tags: diablo-iii

I have beat the game in normal in Asia server but when I open the quest list I don't see the higher difficulty. Why?

Here is a picture of my quest selection screen;

[image]

Comment: My character is lvl 32

Comment: You have not completd the game.  You still have Act IV to complete.

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced that back then, you might have skipped a quest. Double check your quest list across all acts and that nothing is greyed out.

Answer (score 0):

A friend of mine had the same problem. He had to kill a boss he skipped "by accident".

He joined a game where this one boss (for example Azmodan) already has been killed and then helped killing diablo in this particular game and then wondered, why he can't play on the next higher difficulty. He then had to do the whole "Azmodan - quest" to play on a higher difficulty.

Answer (score -1):

Once you have beat the game you can start a new game on nightmare with the same character. You do have to start a new game as you start back at the very beginning with your character. You will still be the same level and have all of your equipment, but the monsters will be stronger and the game in general a little more difficult to beat.

Comment: Start a new game by clicking "change quest" then select difficulty in "Quest Selection", right? But i only see the normal difficulty.

Comment: only thing i can think of is that you haven't completed the game then, because you should be able to switch to nightmare now. complete the last quest "Prime Evil" in Act IV again and then see if it works >.>